# Unable to left align sidebar links keeping them centered

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a navbar where the links are vertically centered. What I've been trying to achieve is make all the links left-aligned, i.e. all the links should start from the left but keeping them centered.

As you can see from the snippet that the links are centered(which I want) but there isn't any alignment. I want the links to start from the same line. Something like this:

```
Home
About Us
Products
Contact Us
```

but should be centered on the navbar.

This is the code I tried:

```css
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://i.ibb.co/1TBvfyP/1.jpg);
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0px 10px 15px 5px #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.nav-sidebar .logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 1px #000);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 2px #000);
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 185px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li {}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li a {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 nopadding">

    <div class="nav-sidebar">

      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RQGBXjK/logo.png">
      </div>

      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I achieve that? It would be great if someone could help a noob in need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the CSS. I've commented out a lot of the styles you had, and added a couple to show the effect better. The main code that does what you want is this:

```
.nav-sidebar .main-nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background: transparent;
}


.container{
    background: transparent;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    /*height: 100vh;*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(https://i.ibb.co/1TBvfyP/1.jpg);
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), 
                0px 10px 15px 5px #000;
    z-index: 9999;
    width:200px;
}


.nav-sidebar .logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}


.logo img{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 1px #000);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 2px #000);
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.nav-sidebar .main-nav{
    /*width: 100%;
    height: 185px;*/
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    /*margin: 0;*/
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li{
}
/*.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li a{
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}*/
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 nopadding">

      <div class="nav-sidebar">

         <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RQGBXjK/logo.png">
         </div>

         <div class="main-nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>

      </div>

   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
   </div>

</div>
```

### **Update**

Can also be done this way:

```css
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://i.ibb.co/1TBvfyP/1.jpg);
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0px 10px 15px 5px #000;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 200px;
}

.nav-sidebar .logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 1px #000);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 2px #000);
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 185px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li {}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li a {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 nopadding">

    <div class="nav-sidebar">

      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RQGBXjK/logo.png">
      </div>

      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to achieve this result by keeping ```.main-nav and ul and li``` full width of the navbar? I have some styling to do which requires it to be full width.

Answer (score 1):

"Left centering" the `<a>` tag inside the li, while leaving the li width at 100%.

```
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(https://i.ibb.co/1TBvfyP/1.jpg);
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), 
    0px 10px 15px 5px #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}


.nav-sidebar .logo {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 1px #000);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 2px #000);
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav {
  height: 185px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

I don't know a pure css option for that so here is some jQuery for a quick fix

```
var li_a_width = 0;

jQuery( '.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li a' ).each(function(){
  var ce       = jQuery( this ),
      ce_width = ce.width();

  if ( ce_width > li_a_width ) {
    li_a_width = ce_width;
  }
});

if ( li_a_width > 0 ) {
  jQuery( '.nav-sidebar .main-nav ul li a' ).width( li_a_width );   
}
```

Hope this help =]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I didn't know it could be something to mention before but is it possible to achieve this result by keeping .main-nav and ul and li full width of the navbar? I have some styling to do which requires it to be full width.

Comment: Added some jQuery to achieve what you wanted. Check my edited answer. Hope that help =]

Comment: Hey thanks for the updated answer. But I'll have to choose the other one cause that's pure css and less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using position: fixed to sidebar and justify-content: center to list elements will fix above issue.

```
.nav-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.nav-sidebar ul li a {
    justify-content: start;
}
```